# Is there a way to keep only the bottom part in vis.js timeline frame?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I built the following frame using `vis.js` timeline:

[image]

But I'd like to keep only the bottom part (highlighted in blue). Is there a way to achieve that?

Respectively code:

```js
export const TimelineGraph = (props) => {
  const items = props.items;
  const container = useRef(null);

  const options = {
    showCurrentTime: false
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeline = container.current && new Timeline(container.current, items, options);
  }, [container, items]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className={'container'}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. You just need to add `min` and `max` options to the `options` object, like so:

```js
const options = {
  showCurrentTime: false,
  min: getLowestDate(),
  max: getHighestDate(),
};
```

After that, the upper bar was gone.